# Configuring GET Request from Nifi

Tags: wcf, http, get, apache-nifi

I am trying to access a WCF service from a browser. I am sending a GET request from my browser to a WCF service. For your reference, the detail is as follows of a WCF service is as follows.

The Service Contract definition is as follows:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IBZTsoftsensor_WcfService {

    [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "json/?inputModel={inputModel}")]
      string ExecuteModelJson(string inputModel);
    }
```

And the implementation of this interface is as follows:

```
public string ExecuteModelJson(string inputModel){
  try
  {
    BZTsoftsensor_ModelInput input =   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BZTsoftsensor_ModelInput>(inputModel);
  var results = this.ExecuteModel(input);
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return ex.Message;
  } 
 }
```

When I am accessing this WCF Service **from browser** with the URL

```
http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/json/?inputModel={"Pyro":"30.0","O2":"20.0"}
```

My WCF service is responsing successfully.

However, Using the above URL, when I am configuring `GeTHTTP` Nifi processor, the processor is erroring illegal characters in GET request URL.

Could you please advise me - **what changes I have to made in GET URL , while using GetHTTP processor?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to encode your inputModel parameter, you can use the urlEncode method of NiFi Expression Language:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#urlencode

Try this as the URL property:

http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/json/?inputModel=${literal("{\"Pyro\":\"30.0\",\"O2\":\"20.0\"}"):urlEncode()}

Alternatively since your URL is fixed you can just encode it using an [online encoding tool](http://www.urlencoder.org/), which gives something like this:

http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/json/?inputModel=%7B%22Pyro%22%3A%2230.0%22%2C%22O2%22%3A%2220.0%22%7D%20

Comment: Thanks for pointer. i am bit new to Nifi. Could you please advise me - how should I use expression language.  What will be the URL property value of a GetHTTP processor ?